# Error when attempting to run more than one Coded UI test at a time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have a suite of Coded UI tests that I am running for a web application in IE 8.  I can run any individual test without error.  When I try to run more than one test at a time, only the first test runs without error; as soon as the second test is attempted, I receive the following error:

"COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

And here's the stack trace.  I should add that I've replaced the default UIMap with my own classes defining the UI elements:

```
System.Variant.MarshalHelperConvertObjectToVariant(Object o, Variant& v)
System.StubHelpers.ObjectMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Object objSrc, IntPtr pDstVariant)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IRPFPlayback.ScreenElementFromNativeElement(Object varNativeElement, String technologyName)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FromNativeElement(Object nativeElement, String technologyName)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FromTechnologyElementInternal(IUITechnologyElement technologyElement)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FromTechnologyElement(IUITechnologyElement element)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(IUITechnologyElement element, UITestControl searchContainer)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.get_CurrentDocumentWindow()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Find()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String propertyName)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyInternal[T](String propertyName)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.get_Exists()
VerifySuccessfulLogon()[...]LogOnPage.cs: line 97
AttemptLogOn()[...]WebUITest.cs: line 111
```

Thanks in advance!
-James

Comment: Are you doing anything multithreaded? Timers etc.

Comment: I am not doing any multithreaded work in the Coded UI tests themselves.  In the same project as the Coded UI tests, I have a performance test that uses a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, but that test is not executed when I run my Coded UI tests.  Not sure if that could be affecting anything.

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the window.

```
this.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
```

For example,

To Open Adobe Acrobat Window

```
public class UIAdobeAcrobatProWindow : WinWindow
{        
    public UIAdobeAcrobatProWindow()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Adobe Acrobat Pro", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        **this.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);**
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "AcrobatSDIWindow";
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This will fix the problem, I hope.